# Output the value of field1 * field2 within an entries loop

Tags: channel-entries

I have a template that outputs a csv, php is set to run on input to allow headers to be set.

For each row I need to calculate the result of 2 fields multiplied and output this as a field to the csv.

Are the field values available in PHP?

Or is there another way to mulitply 2 fields in an entries loop?

```
<?php
$csv_ids = $this->EE->input->post('csv_id');

header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=stock_".date("d_m_Y_H_i").".csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
?>
CODE,field1, field2
{exp:channel:entries channel="stock" limit="10000" entry_id="<?=$csv_ids?>"}
{code},{field1},{field2},{field5}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I need 'field5' to be the result of multiplying 'field3' by 'field4'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [MX Calculator](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-calculator) for any calculation.

But possible you can use query module instead of channel:entries (if you have some simple fieldtype which keep they data  regular way). In this case you can do calculation in query:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT field_id_15 AS code, field_id_2 AS field2, field_id_1 AS field1, (field_id_3 * field_id_4) AS field5 FROM exp_channel_data WHERE channel_id = 1 AND entry_id IN (<?=$csv_ids?>) LIMIT 10000"}
    {code},{field1},{field2},{field5}
{/exp:query}
```

Comment: I had hoped that it could have been done without extra plugins, but this one is pretty minimal, thank you.

Comment: EE have math operations for using in conditionals only so far.But if what you show is just some regular fields, you can use default {exp:query} module and  do this calculation directly in sql query. It also will be better by performance then channel:entries if you have many entries. I add example into my answer.

Comment: Yes, of course, I hadn't thought of doing it directly in SQL, thank you.